# How to track python script execution history and collect data that shows what parts of the code were successfully completed?

Tags: python, database, automation, python-requests

I have a ubuntu server virtual machine that runs my python script every day. The script **mainc.py** is selenium-based and used to automate simple tasks on a website. The code:

```
from selenium import webdriver  
import time  
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
 
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors=yes')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.headless = True

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver", options=options)  
print("driver started") 
driver.get("https://example.com")  
print("page opened") 
#click on the login 
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='navbarsExampleContainer']/div/button[2]").click()  
time.sleep(3)  
print("logging in")

driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='login_append']").send_keys("name")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='password_append']").send_keys("password")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='submit_button']").click()  
print("logged in")
time.sleep(5)

driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='navCollapseB']/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]").click()  
print("pressed the last required button. Finished.")
time.sleep(3)  

driver.close()
```

And what should I add to my script so that after every stage of the program it would send the report to some database so I could track the status of completion? I imagine it could be a post request or saving logs in a file. Sorry if I am not specific enough, it is my first time asking on stack overflow.

Comment: standard method in many programs and services (not only in Python) is to use log files (`name.log`) to write any information. It is text file so you can use standard `open()`, `write()`, `close()` for this. You can also open file for writing and use `print(...,  file=file_handler)` to send print to file. But python has also standard module [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) which can save in file - and it may automatically add date and time to every message.

Comment: BTW: linux has even folder `/var/log/` which many programs use to keep logs - and this way you have all logs in one place.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what isn't working about those attempts?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark I haven't tried anything yet, I was just curious what are the ways to do it before starting doing it.

Comment: @furas thank you for your reply! Is there a way to store these log files automatically in the cloud so I could see them without connecting to vm and opening the file?

Comment: I don't know if there is automatic method. But you can run web server on this machine which will serve this file. Even `python -m http.server` can serve files in some folder. Eventually you can write script which will connect to machine and download file to local computer - if you access machine using SSH then you can use command `scp` (secure copy) to copy file using SSH. And last idea: you can create script which will run on machine and it will send information on your mail.